# Special radio buttons not working on internet explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to implement radio buttons and I style them so the buttons themselves wont show up.
This works great with any other browser that I tried except internet explorer.

```
.img > input[type=radio]{
display:none;
}

input[type=radio] + img{
cursor:pointer;
border:2px solid transparent;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img{
border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

The above code works with internet explorer only if I stop hide the radio buttons with the display:none code. Then the styles below are getting applied and the rest of my jquery code works as well. However if the display:none is "active" and the radio buttons are not showing then internet explorer wont apply the other styles below and my jquery code wont execute either.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Confused with what you're asking. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Btw, cool effect on select :)

Answer (score 1):

In IE, a radio button with display:none will not get checked. What you need to do is position the radio button element off the screen by specifying something like:

```
left: -9999px
position: absolute (or relative depending on your layout)
```

instead of:

```
display:none
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work because they are getting maybe limited by the parent container? The buttons are still showing.

Comment: Try setting the position to either absolute or relative ... depending on what you want.

Comment: Yes, setting position:absolute made them disappear but still nothing happens when I click the images since I still need to click the radio buttons. I think I will just use jquery for this or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Well I ended up modifying my jquery code and checking for image clicks, then I selected the radio button programmatically and I executed the code as it was. Internet exploder is there to give us the chance to write more code. Cool :D Thanks for the help and the compliment anyway Nick.

Answer (score 0):

I've found if I replace

```
display: none;
```

with the following (code below) the text fields still allow for selection without radio buttons displaying.

```
border:none;
width:0%;
height:0%;
font-size:0%;
```